# jQueryUI - Accordion - Setting ID from a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

First off THANK YOU for all that provide input across this site.  It has helped me tremendously in finding answers to questions.  This is my first post here and hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

I am working on a site currently and trying to setup a rather large accordion setup (30+ accordions).  I was searching for answers and found [This Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918790/jquery-accordion-opening-with-href-link) which provides great information and what I'm trying to accomplish minus one thing.

The ID is set from text that is displayed in the < h3> tag. I have a rather long < h3> as I am pulling in a abbreviation and description of the event from a database. (example: AAM - Apparel & Accessories Marketing Series).  I can get this to work but the ID would be something like "aam_-_apparel"...etc.

I need to be able to create the ID to be whatever is after the # in a href="#myNameHere" which would be the abbreviation only. (Abbreviation & Description need to show in the h3)

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="#link1">Link1</a></h3>
<div>content</div>
</div>
```

If you change the "Link1" to say "Link1Test" it will then change the ID to "Link1Test".

```
$(function() {
  var $accordion = $("#accordion").accordion({active: false, collapsible: true}),
  hashId = 0;

if (window.location.hash) {
  $accordion.children('h3').each(function(i){
    var txt = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,'_');
    this.id = txt;
    if (txt === window.location.hash.slice(1)) {
      hashId = i;
    }
  });

  $accordion.accordion({
    active: hashId,
    animate: true,
    heightStyle: 'content',
    collapsible: true,
    create: function( event, ui ) {
      $accordion.children('h3').each(function(i){
        $(this).before('<a class="accordion-link link" data-index="' + i + '" href="#' + this.id + '"></a>');
      });
      $accordion.find('.accordion-link').click(function(){
        $accordion.accordion( "option", "active", $(this).data('index') );
      });
    }
});
}
});
```

Thank you for all that help and chime in, your time and knowledge is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `href` attribute of the anchors are being set from the `id` attributes of the headers; these `id`s are being set from the `txt` variable in the first `.each` call. Thus that's what we want to edit, and we can use [`.indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) on a preset delimiter to extract the first few characters:

```
  var DELIMITER = '_-_';
  $accordion.children('h3').each(function(i){
    var txt = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,'_');
    txt = txt.slice(0, txt.indexOf(DELIMITER)); // <- extracts Abbreviation
    this.id = txt;
    if (txt === window.location.hash.slice(1)) {
      hashId = i;
    }
  });
```

This assumes that all your headers follow the pattern "Abbreviation - Description". If it's a different pattern, just change the `DELIMITER` value. (Can also be just `DELIMITER = "-"` if you don't mind the trailing underscore)

Now, if there are multiple patterns, you can split that `.slice` call across either multiple conditions, or use a regex to combine them all:

```
  var DELIMITERS = ["_-_", "_:_"]; // <- backslash-escape special characters here
  // and then...
    txt = txt.replace(new RegExp("(" + DELIMITERS.join("|")) + ").*"), "");
```

---

It's safe to have multiple instances of the `DELIMITER` in the description, as both `.indexOf` and the regex match will return the first instance. Since this is editing the `txt` value *before* it's actually used anywhere, it should be compatible with the rest of your code